# laravel request is undefined

Tags: angularjs, laravel, request, http-post

I am a newbie in Laravel, so everything is under exploration period. I use angular http post to send data over to laravel and in laravel controller i am able to

```
dd($request)

Request {#40
  #json: ParameterBag {#32
    #parameters: array:4 [
      "GPTour_id" => 1
      "customer_id" => 1
      "status" => "Confirmed"
      "note" => "asdfasdf"
    ]
  }
  #userResolver: Closure {#300
    class: "Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider"
    this: AuthServiceProvider {#22 …}
    use: array:1 [
      "$app" => Application {#3
        #basePath: "/Users/haophung/Dropbox/server/websites/nglaravelyep/laravel-backend"
        #hasBeenBootstrapped: true
        #booted: true
        #bootingCallbacks: []
```

However, if i use

```
$request->input('key')
```

i got $request is undefined. Please advise!!!

```
public function addGospelCustomer(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request) {
            $customer_id = $request->get('customer_id');
            $tour_id = $request->get('GPTour_id');
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'customer_id' =>'required'
            ]);

            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 406);
            }
            $gospel_customer = Gospel_tour::find($tour_id)->with(['customers' => function($query) {
                $query->where('id', $customer_id);
            }])->first();

            if ($gospel_customer === 'null') {
                return response()->json(['error' => "The Customer is already on the list"], 406);
            }

            return 'success';//response()->json(['success' => $request], 200);
        }else {
            return response()->json(['error' =>'can not add customer'], 401);
        }
    }
```

ErrorException in GospelController.php line 60:
Undefined variable: customer_id

I think the problem is

```
    $gospel_customer = Gospel_tour::find($tour_id)->with(['customers' => function($query) {
        $query->where('id', $customer_id);
    }])->first();
```

I can echo $customer_id out, but in this eloquent is not defined

Comment: `$request->get("key");`
how about?

Comment: Check my update to fix your error. You need to add `use($customer_id) `

Comment: if i dd($request->get('key') i got the value. i don't know why if assigned to a var it doesn't work.

Comment: Just check my update for a fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to typehint requestion in your function definition

```
public function name(Request $request) {}
```

And use it like

```
$key = $request->key;
$key = $request->get('key');
```

Or use the global function

```
$key = request('key');
```

**Update**

Where you have the error exception do

```
$gospel_customer = Gospel_tour::find($tour_id)->with(['customers' => function($query) use ($customer_id) {
     $query->where('id', $customer_id);
}]);
```

The error occurs because you are inside a closure, and it doesn't have access to external variables.

Comment: I did typehing @EddyTheDove

Comment: Even with the global helper? Please add your controller to your question and let's see.